# Callback для liqpay

Tags: php, wordpress

Пытаюсь работать с платёжной системой liqpay, в апи настраиваются два url: `result_url и server_url`. Первый отправляет пользователя на эту страницу, если он перейдёт по ссылке "вернуться на сайт" после оплаты, второй url обрабатывает данные, если пользователь после оплаты решил не переходить назад на сайт.
С сервера `liqpay` ответ возвращается в `$_POST`.
Создал такой callback:

```
add_action('the_content', function($content){

    if(is_page('checkout')) { //проверим чтобы код не срабатывал на всех страницах
        if (isset($_POST['data'])) {

            $result = json_decode(base64_decode($_POST['data']));
            // данные вернуться в base64 формат JSON

            if ($result->status == 'success') {
                ob_start();
                echo '<div class="test1"><pre>';
                var_export($result);
                echo '</pre></div>';
                $body = ob_get_clean();
                wp_mail('mail@gmail.com', 'from checkout', 'Какое-то сообщение checkout . body = ' . $body);
            }
        }
    }
    return $content;
});
```

Правильный ли я использую хук? И почему этот callback не срабатывает на хук `init`? `the_content` правильно принимает данные и обрабатывает $_POST

Comment: Ты ликпей к Вукомерс конектишь или у тебя кастомная форма с оплатой за что-то ? Так работает или нет ?

Comment: @Pavel8289, вопрос больше по хукам, чем по liqpay. Вышеприведённый код работает. Вопрос в том, почему этот код не работает для хука `init`?

Comment: Если вам надо принимать ответ создайте отдельную страницу для приёма, не делайте это на хуках... Подгрузите ядро(wp-load.php) и в ней обработайте ответ без показа фронта

Answer (score 2):

Код не работает на хуке `init`, потому что ещё рано. На этом этапе главный цикл WordPress не установлен. И хотя функция `is_page()` уже существует, но возвращает она всегда `false`.

Ваш код сможет работать, например, на хуке `wp`:

```
<?php
add_action(
    'wp',
    function () {
        if ( is_page( 'checkout' ) ) { // Проверим, чтобы код не срабатывал на всех страницах.
            if ( isset( $_POST['data'] ) ) {

                $result = json_decode( base64_decode( $_POST['data'] ) ); // Данные вернутся в base64 формат JSON.

                if ( 'success' === $result->status ) {
                    ob_start();
                    echo '<div class="test1"><pre>';
                    var_export( $result );
                    echo '</pre></div>';
                    $body = ob_get_clean();
                    wp_mail( 'mail@gmail.com', 'from checkout', 'Какое-то сообщение checkout . body = ' . $body );
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Подробнее о порядке загрузки WordPress [здесь](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).

Answer (score 1):

Если надо обработать ответ на отдельной странице создайте её, подгрузите часть ядра например создаём странице для получения ответа request_liqpay.php

```
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );
wp_mail(***);
// если нужен доступ к базе
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert/update/get_result и прочие действия
die();
```

Comment: что-то не работает ни отправка почты, ни сохранение в бд, хоть и указал `server_url = "http://site.ru/request_liqpay.php`.Вордпресс наверно блокирует этот url.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пару дней назад реализовал прослушку callback. 
Через функцию [register_rest_route()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_rest_route) регистрируем URL по которому будет срабатывать код для обработки callback. То есть не вздумайте создавать из админки пустые страницы.

Пример кода для проверки подлинности подписи (в файле который указали в параметре `server_url`):

```
if ( isset( $_POST['data'] ) ) {
  $data = $_POST['data']; 
} else {
  wp_die();
}

if ( isset( $_POST['signature'] ) ) {
  $signature = $_POST['signature'];
} else {
  wp_die();
}

$private_key = 'Ваш ключ';

//формируем нашу подпись
$my_signature = base64_encode( sha1(
  $private_key .
  $data .
  $private_key
  , 1 ));

if ( $my_signature === $signature ) {
  // делаем проверку на каждый статус ответа по платежу
} else {
  wp_die();
}
```